# Dynamic way of returning list with Anonymous types in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have used the code as below which returns all fields. How can I make it return a list with anonymous types.

Here is the code I used:

```
public List<T> GetList<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, Func<T, T> select,
       params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties) where T : class
{
    var database = new ProjectIVModel();
    IQueryable<T> dbQuery = database.Set<T>();

    foreach (Expression<Func<T,object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);
    }

    if (where != null)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(where as Expression<Func<T, bool>>);
    }

    var list = dbQuery
              .AsNoTracking()
              .Select(select)
              .ToList<T>();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: "_a list with anonymous types_" can be declaerd as `List<object>` or `List<dynamic>` but everything depends on what are your needs. Please edit your question, add more details to it.

Comment: What @Mateusz said and in any case you shouldn't use List<T> as your return type as in your code T refers to an entity and not an anonymous type.